# Virtual Studio C++ Error: "Expression: string subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string key = "XZNLWEBGJHQDYVTKFUOMPCIASRxznlwebgjhqdyvtkfuompciasr";

    string secret_message;
    string encrypted_message;
    string decrypted_message;

    cout << "What message would you like to encrypt?" << endl << endl;

    getline(cin, secret_message);

    for (int i{ 0 }; i >= 0 && i < secret_message.length(); i++) {

        if (isalpha(secret_message[i])) {
            size_t pos = alphabet.find(secret_message[i]);
            encrypted_message[i] = key[pos];
        }

        else {
            encrypted_message[i] = secret_message[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "Encrypting message...." << endl << "Encrypted Message: " << encrypted_message << endl << endl;

}
```

## **Problem Statement**

I am writing basic C++ code trying to build a basic encryption program. The only error I am receiving is from Virtual Studio saying that the string subscript is out of range. After reviewing other stackoverflow posts related to this, I found that it has to do with i being negative or something in the for loop, but I do not fully understand what is wrong and cannot figure out how to resolve the issue.

I have tried to change around the contents of the for loop parameters, but to no resolve.

Comment: `encrypted_message` is an empty string. `encrypted_message[i] = key[pos];` and `encrypted_message[i] = secret_message[i];` attempt to write out of bounds for a string of 0 characters.

Comment: in `encrypted_message[i] = key[pos];` thou shalt not use `pos` as an index before using it to confirm that the item was found.

Comment: Side note: this is one of those times when undefined behaviour (UB) is your friend. Microsoft didn't have to put the bounds check that caught the mistake there, they didn't have to do anything, but with out of bounds accesses being UB, they are allowed to do whatever the heck they want. This time they wanted to do you a favour by checking. This makes the debug build (you can be pretty sure the check isn't there in the release build) a bit slower, but what's a debug build for if not to find bugs?

Comment: Weird. I expected my comment to be a futurebug at best. You should have hit 
the problem pointed out by drescherjm and pm100 first.

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize `encrypted_message` to be the size you need, do this

```
getline(cin, secret_message);
string encrypted_message (secret_message.length(), ' ');
```